# Computing conditional expectation of function of Ito process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

In some projects I got to a conditional expectation of the form:

$$E\left[\exp\left\{\int_s^tX(r)f(r)dr\right\}\mid\mathcal F_s\right]$$

where $t\geq s$, $f$ is nice enough and $X$ is an Ito process and $\mathcal F_s$ is the information about $X$ up to time $s$. I want to compute this. Is there anyway to do so?

I tried Taylor expanding $\exp$, I tried to apply Ito formula in a few clever ways and nothing works out nicely. Is there anyway of computing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer*.
I'm using $T$ instead of $t$ for the terminal time and $t_0$ instead of $s$ for the initial time.
I am ignoring issues arising due to a lack of regularity and, as you say, assuming that the drift, diffusion, and $f$ are nice enough.

Since $X$ is an Ito process and hence Markov, it is sufficient to consider
$$
v(t,x)\equiv\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{\int_{t}^{T}X(s)f(s)ds\right\}\,\middle|\, X(t)=x\right].
$$
By the [Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula), it follows that
\begin{align*}
v_{t}+Lv+xfv & =0, & \text{on }[t_{0},T)\times\mathbb{R}\phantom{.}\\
v(T,\cdot) & =1, & \text{on }\mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}
where $L$ is the [infinitesimal generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)#Generators_of_some_common_processes) of $X$.

You can [solve this PDE numerically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_partial_differential_equations) to get the value of $v(t_0, X(t_0))$.
Alternatively, you can use [Monte Carlo simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) on the original expectation, but this is generally slower than the solving the PDE numerically due to the problem's low dimensionality.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot.